# Replicating Excel's IndexMatch in Python with Pandas

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel spreadsheet that I update frequently (2-3 times a day). This update entails running an index-match to pull values from a table in another spreadsheet and write them to a column in the first one. The values are overwriting old ones, not creating a new column.

I would like to automate this procedure using pandas (and xlwings to write the data to the spreadsheet, but I'm having no issues with that part). The first step is replicating excel's INDEXMATCH() with pandas. In total, the function should:

- take arguments that are the string headers of the column to be indexed, the column to be written over, and the columns that contain the values being used to match the read & write columns
- iterate down the write column; on every iteration, search the read column for the value whose corresponding match column-value matches the write column's match column-value
- if there is no matching value, write NaN or '#N/A' to the dataframe (important to distinguish between a 0 and a non-match)

I expected there to be a native vlookup/indexmatch functionality in pandas, but the only things I could find were about joining or merging dataframes, which isn't what I want to do--I want to overwrite the individual values in the dataframe, and do so in an arbitrary index order.

I've managed to get it working with a script-specific function that's very ugly, but I decided it would be useful to try generalizing the function for other uses. After some cleaning and rewriting, I've got the following:

```
##Index Match in Python with pandas
#Remember that dataframes start at 0, excel starts at 1
#This only works if both DFs have the same indices (integers, strings, whatever)
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#sample dataframes
d = {'Match Column' : [0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,7.,'string'],
     'Read Column' : ['zero','one','two','three','four','seven','string']}

dfRead = pd.DataFrame(d)

d2 = {'Match Column' : [0.,1.,2.,3.,4.,5.,6.,7.,'8'],
      'Write Column' : [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'0']}

dfWrite = pd.DataFrame(d2)

#test arguments
ReadColumn = 'Read Column'
WriteColumn = 'Write Column'
ReadMatchColumn = 'Match Column'
WriteMatchColumn = 'Match Column'

def indexmatch(dfRead, dfWrite, ReadColumn, WriteColumn, ReadMatchColumn, WriteMatchColumn, skiprows=0):
#convert the string inputs to a column number for each dataframe
    RCNum = np.where(dfRead.columns == ReadColumn)[0][0]
    WCNum = np.where(dfWrite.columns == WriteColumn)[0][0]
    RMCNum = np.where(dfRead.columns == ReadMatchColumn)[0][0]
    WMCNum = np.where(dfWrite.columns == WriteMatchColumn)[0][0]

    for i in range(skiprows,len(dfWrite.index),1):
        match = dfWrite.loc[dfWrite.index[i]][WMCNum] #the value we're using to match the columns    
        try:
            matchind = dfRead.index[np.where(dfRead[ReadMatchColumn] == match)[0][0]]
            value = dfRead.fillna('#N/A').loc[matchind][RCNum] #replaces DF NaN values with excel's #N/A, optional method
            dfWrite.set_value(dfWrite.index[i],WriteColumn,value)
        except KeyError:
            dfWrite.set_value(dfWrite.index[i],WriteColumn,np.nan) #if there is no match, write NaN to the 'cell'
        except IndexError:
            dfWrite.set_value(dfWrite.index[i],WriteColumn,np.nan)
```

This works, but it isn't pretty, and it doesn't account for when you want to match a column to another dataframe's index (for instance, matching a dataframe to a pivot table dataframe).

Is there a more robust--and concise--method of doing this?

As requested, the expected input and output:

```
In [2]: dfRead
Out[2]: 
  Match Column Read Column
0            0        zero
1            1         one
2            2         two
3            3       three
4            4        four
5            7       seven
6       string      string

In [3]: dfWrite
Out[3]: 
  Match Column Write Column
0            0            0
1            1            0
2            2            0
3            3            0
4            4            0
5            5            0
6            6            0
7            7            0
8            8            0

In [4]: indexmatch(dfRead, dfWrite, 'Read Column', 'Write Column', 'Match Column', 'Match Column')
In [5]: dfWrite
Out[7]: 
  Match Column Write Column
0            0         zero
1            1          one
2            2          two
3            3        three
4            4         four
5            5          NaN
6            6          NaN
7            7        seven
8            8          NaN
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple, reproducible example and desired output? Depending on what you're trying to do `pandas` is not meant to be used like Excel so there could be a better way that can be explained after you provide an example.

Comment: Certainly, my bad for not doing so originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pd.Series.map` will take a Series as an argument, treating it like it would if fed a dictionary with the indices as keys.

Applied here, that looks like

```
dfWrite['Write Column'] = dfWrite['Match Column'].map(dfRead.set_index('Match Column')['Read Column'])

dfWrite
Out[409]: 
  Match Column Write Column
0            0         zero
1            1          one
2            2          two
3            3        three
4            4         four
5            5          NaN
6            6          NaN
7            7        seven
8            8          NaN
```

Giving identical output to

```
indexmatch(dfRead, dfWrite, 'Read Column', 'Write Column', 'Match Column', 'Match Column')

dfWrite
Out[413]: 
  Match Column Write Column
0            0         zero
1            1          one
2            2          two
3            3        three
4            4         four
5            5          NaN
6            6          NaN
7            7        seven
8            8          NaN
```

To match on the index of `dfRead`, skip the `.set_index(...)` step. To match on the index of `dfWrite`, replace `dfWrite['Match Column'].map` with `dfWrite.index.to_series().map`

Comment: Awesome! Clean, simple, and most importantly it lets you match an index to another df's column. Exactly the kind of built-in solution I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `merge` function as well:

```
dfWrite = pd.merge(left=dfWrite.ix[:,['Match Column']], right=dfRead, on='Match Column', how='left')

dfWrite.rename(columns={'Read Column':'Write Column'}, inplace=True)
```